# Active Record equivalent to this MySQL query - CodeIgniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, activerecord

I just wanted some help figuring out how I would insert data that was coming out of a multiple select box, being put into a variable and then into a database.

My database table is structured like this - Table: `prd_attr`

```
ID | Product_ID | name | value
-------------------------------
1  | 3          | size | large
2  | 3          | size | medium
```

So say I have a multiple select box with the name `sizes[]`, and the admin selects 2 sizes for a product to enter into the database. I can get these values in the controller and put them into a variable:

```
$sizes = $_GET['sizes'];
```

and pass that variable to the model. Once its there, I can insert the data as a MySQL query like this:

```
foreach ($sizes as $s)
{
    $query = mysql_query("insert into prd_attr ('name', 'value') VALUES ('size','$s')");
}
```

But I've learned that mysql_* is deprecated, and since I'm using a framework which provides Active Records I'd like to make use of that. I know the basics of Active Record, but since this is a foreach loop over a variable which can hold any number of values, I don't know how to include a foreach statement with Active Records.

Could someone please explain? Thank you for any help.

Comment: The mysql_* functions are deprecated. Use PDO or MySQLi! http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use batch insert in codeigniter:

Try this:

```
function insert_sizes()
{
    $sizes  =   $this->input->get('sizes');
    foreach ($sizes as $s)
    {
        $data[] = array(
          'name' => 'size',
          'value' => $s
        );
    }
    $this->db->insert_batch('prd_attr',$data);
}
```

For more details: 
http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html

Comment: I was looking at insert_batch! but was confused as the documentation showed that it was an array with arrays inside. I need to learn to take a hint! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use this in Model of Codeigniter.  Here is a method

```
function insert_sizes()
{
    $sizes  =   $this->input->get('sizes');
    $data['name']   =   'size';
    foreach ($sizes as $s)
    {
        $data['value']  =   $s;
        $this->db->insert('prd_attr',$data);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is $data['size'] corresponding to the column name in my database? In that case would it need to be $data['name'] = 'size'; ?

Comment: Yes you are right. Sorry i mistyped it should be $data['name']   =   'size';

Comment: Thank you, also just wondering does it conform to MVC that you are receiving the input from the view directly in the model? I was told views and models can't directly interact

Comment: yes i am doing same if it is not working for you than get it in Controller and pass to model method